# Does $f(x) = x - \tanh(x)$ have an inverse function that can be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Tags: inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions, elementary-functions

I find this question relevant in my current study of the tractrix, namely because this expression appears in one parameterization of the curve. I’ve noticed that the plot of the Cartesian equation of the tractrix appears to be the graph of a function. As you may have guessed, I became interested in discovering this function, and led myself to this question.

If $x - \tanh(x)$ does indeed have an elementary inverse, I’m more interested in how to derive an expression for it than the expression itself. If it doesn’t, I’d like to know why.

Comment: Would the Lambert-W-function qualify as "elementary" ? However, I am not sure whether there is an inverse involving this function, but it might be the case.

Comment: @Peter I wouldn’t count it as elementary, but an expression involving the Lambert W relation is definitely better than nothing.

Comment: As far as Maple can tell, there is no way to do this using Lambert W either.

Comment: Most functions you can write down will not have elementary inverses. *Polynomials* don't even have "elementary" inverses in general (when restricted to domains where they are invertible at all). It is well-known that there are degree 5 (and higher) polynomials whose roots cannot be expressed in terms of radicals.

Comment: There are ways to use more general Wolfram inverse functions for the inverse, no Root-of function nor numerical methods. Would an answer with these functions be of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not a solution in elementary functions**
We can do this with series reversion.  As $x \to 0$ we have
$$
x - \tanh x = 
{\frac{1}{3}}{x}^{3}-{\frac{2}{15}}{x}^{5}+{\frac{17}{315}}{x}^{7}-{
\frac{62}{2835}}{x}^{9}+O \left( {x}^{11} \right) 
$$
Solving $y=x-\tanh x$, we get as $y \to 0$
$$
x = {3}^{1/3}\,{y}^{1/3}+\frac{2}{5}\,y+{\frac {9\cdot{3}^{2/3}}{175}}{y}^{5/3}+{
\frac {2\cdot{3}^{1/3}}{175}}{y}^{7/3}+O \left( {y}^{3} \right) 
$$

Comment: Yes, you are right, after solving $z^3=x^3-\frac25x^5+...$ to get $x=z+..$ as power series in $z$, one has to finish with $y=\frac13z^3$ by inserting $z=(3y)^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Inverse functions are sometimes transcendental in nature, cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Way to derive 3D coordinates of *asymptotic lines on a pseudosphere for tractrix* , in polar/cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z$ ):

$$ \sin \psi = \sin \phi = r/a = \frac{r d\theta}{ds}$$
$$ dr/ds= \sin \phi  \cos \psi, dz/ds=\cos \phi \cos \psi $$
Integrating with initial conditions $ (z=0, r=a) $ you get:
$$ z/a= \theta - \tanh \theta,\, r/a= \operatorname{sech} \,\theta. $$

We have parametric $ r(\theta), z(\theta)$ and there would perhaps be no  need to find an inverse function.

[image: r_th_ps]

We can find $z$ for any $\theta.  $ Explicitly solving for $z$ is not possible analytically but possible only numerically.

[image: r_th_graph3D_PS]

Image from an earlier post here.